# Reallocate Swap Space

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

I have a PC with 4 GB ram and while installing I allocated a 40 GB partition as swap space (Overkill right!!). Now I check the amount of space that was utilised and it was just 0.4% of the 40GB. I decided to relieve the space using Gparted but there is no option to resize it. I believe resizing is possible only is swap is turned off(correct me if I am wrong).

I want to allocate 4-6GB of swap space but I have no idea how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and [How to increase the size of linux-swap partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367331/how-to-increase-the-size-of-linux-swap-partition)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to boot from a USB drive with the Ubuntu live edition or some other bootable linux and then run gparted from there. You can then change the swap partition size and add the freed up space to your root partition (the one mounted as /).

Comment: Will reallocation affect my current Ubuntu data?